# How to find the probability for Markov chain discrete time parameter?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains

SO I just study the Markov chain which seems to be very powerful tools of what of have learned, So I got the Idea Markov chain only require the repetitive event like if today sunny will tomorrow sunny or the next n period will be sunny.

So I thought of what if I used it in the stock market. But when I start to think of that "ONE THING" is showing up from what the textbook did not tell me.

**"IT GIVE THE PROBABILITY RIGHT AWAY"** what actually I had read is conditional probability that does not require the probability of that event alone.

So here is what I want to apply and would like you to make a suggestion on whether it works or not.

Use Markov chain for Calculating the **risk** of investing in one stock ABC, on the probability that whether the next event is **UP** or **DOWN**

So Stock market obviously did not provide the probability of Up and Down.
So I come up with the counting method

Pr(Up) = N(Up)/N

Pr(Down) = N(Down)/N

Basically, the probability of up is the proportion of event that is up to the total event. same goes for Pr(Down)

*In order to do the Markov chain, I need conditional probability.*

I hope this is valid as the event is discrete time parameter and this method do not violate the Axioms of probability

Example 
       Event for one month of ABC stock
U stands for the closing price of that day is positive 
D stands for the closing price of that day is negative

Month N : UUUUDDDUUUDUDUUUDUUDDUUUDDDUDU

N(U) = 18
N(D) = 12

P(U) = 18/30
P(D) = 12/30

Now if I want to derive the conditional probability. 
U,D is no longer U,D it becomes  $U_{i}$ $D_{i}$ and i = 1,2,...,30

Recall the conditional probability

Pr(A|B) = Pr(A,B)/Pr(B)

Pr(A, B) = P($U_{i+1}$,$U_{i}$) the joint probability for the event that the in the next day it will increase in price after that it had increased.

So here it starts.

Pr($U_{i+1}$|$U_{i}$) = N($U_{i+1}$,$U_{i}$)/N($U_{i}$)
Start counting

N($U_{i+1}$,$U_{i}$) = 10
N($U_{i}$) = 18

Pr($U_{i+1}$|$U_{i}$) = 10/18

So I skipped the counting part so that it is not consumed a lot of space

Pr($U_{i+1}$|$U_{i}$) =  10/18

Pr($D_{i+1}$|$U_{i}$) =   8/18

Pr($U_{i+1}$|$D_{i}$) =   5/12

Pr($D_{i+1}$|$D_{i}$) =   7/12

Now we can draw the transition matrix but I don't know how to do it here, therefore I will just stop here..

**Thank you for your support !!!!**

Comment: It seems to me like you are recreating the binomial tree method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model#Method (ignore the stuff about pricing options and just look at how the stock is modeled).

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix}q(U\mid U)&q(D\mid U)\\q(U\mid D)&q(D\mid D)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}10/18&8/18\\5/12&7/12\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. @parsiad but I don't get whether you are saying it is work or not? and the method you give me is **Great!!** it accounts the variation which can apply for price prediction but I think if I really only want to know whether it will increase or decrease what you give might be too complicated. Thank you

Comment: Rough and sometimes successful Markov models have been made to predict the stock market. Probably the most successful have been kept private. The easiest Markov models to handle are _time invariant._ For example, $P(\text{U tomorrow}|\text{U today})$ does not change as time goes on. A difficulty in making realistic Markov models for the market is that the market is not time-invariant.

Comment: @BruceET Do you have any suggestion on reading any book or topics in that Markov chains?